# What does "Transform Ship" do? It has keybinding T for it

Tags: sunless-sea

When I go to Options -> Keybindings, there is T for "Transform Ship". What does it do? Google searching "Sunless sea Transform ship" gives nothing.

Comment: Why not press T and see what happens?

Comment: Nothing that I noticed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new keybinding is part of the [Zubmariner](http://steamcommunity.com/games/304650/announcements/detail/930377794645207516) expansion to Sunless Sea, which was released on October 11, 2016. That expansion is all about exploring the sea floor.

Once you complete a decent-sized quest a Port Carnelian, pressing T will transform your ship into a zubmarine. Then you'll immediately dive.